# hyperref error: Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

The hyperref package is returning the following error when I try to compile the pdf:

```
Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par
l.45
```

The line 45 is just an empty line between my paragraphs, there is no `\ref` or `\label` command. If I comment the `\usepackage{hyperref}` statement the document compiles successfully. I'm using the template from overleaf that can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-journal-of-complex-networks-comnet/wcdcwhqgkddf#.WSmLthMrIy4). I tried several solutions from similar errors but none worked for me. Couldn't find open `{}` or other inconsistency. Deleting `.aux` files, compiling online on overleaf or local via texstudio and teXshop also doesn't work and return the same error message.

My document follows the structure bellow:

```
\documentclass{comnet}  % class from journal of complex networks
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{;}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{algorithmicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}           


\begin{document}

\title{Complicated title}
\shorttitle{Complicated title}
\shortauthorlist{author 1, author 2}

\author{
\name{author 1}
\address{springfield}
\name{author 2}
\address{springfield}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    {abstract text}
    {key words}
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
\section{section 1}   
\subsection{section 1.1}   
\section{section 2}    
\section{Conclusion}    

\bibliographystyle{comnet}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

I also noted that if I comment the `maketitle` command the document is able to compile. Can anyone give a clue of what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 13):

The error comes not directly from `\maketitle` itself, but from the `\thispagestyle{plain}` macro usage in `\maketitle`.

The `plain` page style is defined in `comnet.cls` as

```
\def\ps@plain{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\gridpl\hfill\fontsize{6.8}{9}\selectfont  $\copyright$
    The author \number\year. Published by Oxford University Press on behalf of
    the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications. All rights reserved.}
  % \let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evnhead{\CROPMARKSA}%
  \def\@oddhead{\CROPMARKSA\begin{tabular}{@{}l}\\[-1pt]\textit{IMA Journal of Complex Networks} (\number\year) Page \fpage\ of\hspace*{2pt} \lpage\\doi:10.1093/comnet/\@kxi\end{tabular}
  }%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
}
```

Now, `\fpage` and `\lpage` (used in `\@oddhead`) are shortcuts to

```
\AtBeginDocument{\label{FirstPage}}
\def\lpage{\pageref{LastPage}}
\def\fpage{\pageref{FirstPage}}
```

Here the real error comes in: `\label{FirstPage}` is written at the start of the document, due to the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, but `hyperref` is loaded later on, redefining the `\label` etc. macros with additional information on the labeling, meaning that `\label{FirstPage}` writes too few information to the `.aux` file for `hyperref` to grab it with the redefined `\pageref` command.

A look into the `.aux` file after first compilation run of the document shows (unnecessary information not given here) -- the first run is 'ok', the second compilation shows the error then!

```
\newlabel{FirstPage}{{}{1}}
...
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{2}{}{page.2}{}}
```

It is obvious, that `LastPage` has more information 'slots' (especially the `page.2` anchor) which is expected by `hyperref` to be read, but this does not work for `Firstpage`.

The solution is to change `\fpage` to `\def\fpage{\pageref{CorrectFirstPageLabel}}` and add the `CorrectFirstPageLabel` **after** loading of `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{comnet}  % class from journal of complex networks
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{;}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{algorithmicx}       
\usepackage{hyperref}           

\usepackage{blindtext}



\AtBeginDocument{
  \label{CorrectFirstPageLabel}
  \def\fpage{\pageref{CorrectFirstPageLabel}}
}

\begin{document}

\title{Complicated title}
\shorttitle{Complicated title}
\shortauthorlist{author 1, author 2}

\author{%
  \name{author 1}
  \address{springfield}
  \name{author 2}
  \address{springfield}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    {abstract text}
    {key words}
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
\section{section 1}   
\subsection{section 1.1}   
\section{section 2}    
\section{Conclusion}    

\blindtext[5]

\bibliographystyle{comnet}
%\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Another solution would be to redefine `\ps@plain` in order to remove the `\fpage` macro and replace it with `1`, but I don't recommend this, since other authors could make use of `plain` style at places in the document other than for the title page as well.

[image]

The error vanishes of course if `hyperref` is not loaded at all, whether the *Journal of Complex Networks* allows `hyperref`ed document submissions is not known to me. In doubt omit `hyperref` rather then.

**Update**

Here is a minimal non - working version that has the same issue by forcing a label in `\AtBeginDocument` and loading the `hyperref` package after that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \section{Foo}\label{foolabel}
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\ref{foolabel}

\section{Foo again}\label{fooagainlabel}

\ref{fooagainlabel}

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file contains

```
\newlabel{foolabel}{{1}{1}}

\newlabel{fooagainlabel}{{2}{1}{Foo again}{section.2}{}}
```

The `foolabel` is from the regular `\label` command as defined in `latex.ltx`, storing the section number `1` for the first page, whereas the second label definition is extended by `hyperref` to contain

1. section number `2`
2. page number `1`
3. Section title `Foo again`, to be extracted with `\nameref` or `\nameref*`
4. ('unique') hyper anchor name `section.2`
5. 'unused' (empty)

Comment: The class (under a different name) can be obtained from here: https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/class%20file.zip