# creating clickable citations

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, natbib

I am trying to write a paper. The template of the paper is available [at the official website](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/at_download/file)

The template has a few citations in subsection 2.2. 
The problem is when I try to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` (becuase I want to make those references clickable) to the preamble it gives the following error:

```
Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }. Paper Title\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}
```

I tried changing the order of packages but it just gives another error.
Any enlightenment would be great.

Comment: Try removing all the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof`, etc.) and then compiling again.

Comment: tried removing it. no luck

Comment: I would not load `hyperref` in journal/conference templates. If the journal wants to use `hyperref` the template will load it automatically. They may just do things that are incompatible with that package, I don't think you can do a lot in that case. I doubt that they would look favourably upon you messing with the template just to get `hyperref` going.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a great violation to the template but still yeah I agree with you. I just became obsessed with this problem. I just thought I might be using libraries that overlap and which is why I was getting this problem but maybe this is just unacceptable here.

Comment: I haven't had time to look at the class yet. But even if loading `hyperref` does not seem like a big deal and does not dramatically change the output (other than enabling links of course), there is not a lot you can do if the class is incompatible with `hyperref` (intentionally or not). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371955/35864 describes a similar situation.